# User management in asp.net without using cookie or session

Tags: asp.net, session, cookies, user-management

Is it possible to perform user management (store user info, login , logout etc) without using session or cookie?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are cookieless sessions

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx

If you don't want any server-state at all, you need to keep passing the state around in URLs.  For login, you can use an HTTP Auth that the browser understands.

Answer (score 0):

You can try User Profile:
http://quickstarts.asp.net/quickstartv20/aspnet/doc/profile/default.aspx

However, even if you don't explicitly store anything in cookie, ASP.NET will still store something like sessionid in your client cookie if you want to permanently store something.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't wish to use cookies, cookieless session mode can be acivated by adding the following setting to your application's web.config.

```
<sessionState cookieless="true" />
```

With this option, the session ID is inserted in a particular position within the URL. Read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx) for more info.